# How to return ID from stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure where I am passing an ID and wanting to return the selected ID that was given after passing in an ID. Here is what I came up with...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetAdministratorHistoryIDByAdministratorID]
    @AdministratorID int,
    @AdministrationHistoryID int output
AS
DECLARE @ERROR_SEVERITY int,
        @MESSAGE varchar(1000),
        @ERROR_NUMBER int,
        @ERROR_PROCEDURE nvarchar(200),
        @ERROR_LINE int,
        @ERROR_MESSAGE nvarchar(4000);
begin try
    SELECT AdministrationHistoryID
    from [AdministrationHistory]
    where AdministratorID = @AdministratorID
    set @AdministrationHistoryID = AdministrationHistoryID
end try
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @ERROR_SEVERITY = ISNULL(ERROR_SEVERITY(),'');
    SET @ERROR_NUMBER = ISNULL(ERROR_NUMBER(),'');
    SET @ERROR_PROCEDURE = ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),''); 
    SET @ERROR_LINE = ISNULL(ERROR_LINE(),'');
    SET @ERROR_MESSAGE = ISNULL(ERROR_MESSAGE(),'');

    -- Test if the transaction is uncommittable.
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
        BEGIN
            --PRINT N'The transaction is in an uncommittable state. Rolling back transaction.'
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END;

    -- Test if the transaction is active and valid.
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
        BEGIN
            --PRINT N'The transaction is committable. Committing transaction.'
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;   
        END;

    SET @MESSAGE = 'Error Occured in Stored Procedure ' + cast(@ERROR_PROCEDURE as varchar(200)) + 
                    '; Line Number ' + cast(@ERROR_LINE as varchar) + 
                    '; Message: [' + cast(@ERROR_NUMBER as varchar) + '] - '
                    + cast(@ERROR_MESSAGE as varchar(255))

    RAISERROR(@MESSAGE, @ERROR_SEVERITY, 1);
END CATCH;
```

So what I am trying to achieve is by passing the `AdministratorID`, that it selects the `AdministrationHistoryID` from the `AdministrationHistory` table and I want to return that `AdministrationHistoryID` as an `int`.

I have tried executing this and I get an error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_GetAdministratorHistoryIDByAdministratorID, Line 16
>   Invalid column name 'AdministrationHistoryID'.

I know that there is an `AdministrationHistoryID` because it's in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT @AdministrationHistoryID = AdministrationHistoryID
    FROM [AdministrationHistory]
    WHERE AdministratorID = @AdministratorID;
END TRY
```

Keep in mind that if this query returns more than one row you will get last value.

Alternatively:

```
SET @AdministrationHistoryID = (SELECT AdministrationHistoryID
                                FROM [AdministrationHistory]
                                WHERE AdministratorID = @AdministratorID);
```

This may fail if more than one record is returned (add `DISTINCT` or `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY` clause if needed.

Comment: This worked perfectly, it succeeded and returned the AdministrationHistoryID, I'll accept as soon as it lets me

Answer (score 2):

Mind you, you need to begin a transaction before you can commit it or rollback, Also committing your transaction in Catch block means you would not commit a transaction until something has gone wrong in the Try block, which doesnt make any sense.

You would only commit a transaction in try block and only rollback a transaction in catch block. since your control will never enter the catch block unless something went wrong in the try block.

A much simpler version of your stored procedure would be something like.....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetAdministratorHistoryIDByAdministratorID]
    @AdministratorID int,
    @AdministrationHistoryID int output
AS
BEGIN
begin try
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;
     SELECT @AdministrationHistoryID = AdministrationHistoryID
     from [AdministrationHistory]
     where AdministratorID = @AdministratorID
  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
end try
BEGIN CATCH
  IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
    BEGIN
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END

Declare @MESSAGE NVARCHAR(4000);

    SET @MESSAGE = 'Error Occured in Stored Procedure ' + cast(ERROR_PROCEDURE() as varchar(200)) + 
                    '; Line Number ' + cast(ERROR_LINE() as varchar) + 
                    '; Message: [' + cast(ERROR_NUMBER() as varchar) + '] - '
                    + cast(ERROR_MESSAGE() as varchar(255))

    RAISERROR(@MESSAGE, ERROR_SEVERITY(), 1);
END CATCH

END
```